# Changing class properties for all instances

Tags: c#, class, properties, xna

Im making a simple game with Microsoft XNA and I have an `Enemy.cs` class which consists of a property `enemyMoveSpeed`.

```
public class Enemy
{
    float enemyMoveSpeed { get; set }
}
```

In the `Game1.cs` in update section I have put a timer which would constantly change the following property.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    timer -= elapsed;
    if (timer < 0)
    {
        foreach (Enemy E in enemies)
        {
            E.enemyMoveSpeed += 1;
        }

        timer = TIMER; //Reset Timer
    }
}
```

Every new instance of Enemy would be affected after the change. Can somebody give me an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Are you sure it's an attribute and not a field or property?

Comment: I am sorry I am a total beginner still confusing these keywords. You are surely right.

Comment: Could you provide a source code example?

Comment: I have got an Enemy class which contains a float enemyMoveSpeed. This is then initialised with a value of 3.0f within the class in Initialize method. The timer I am using looks like this and takes place in Game1.cs Update method.

Comment: float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            timer -= elapsed;
            if (timer < 0)
            {
                foreach (Enemy E in enemies)
                {
                    E.enemyMoveSpeed += 1;
                }
                  timer = TIMER;   //Reset Timer
            }

Answer (score 1):

Create a List

```
List<Enemy> MyEnemyList;
//of course you will have to add Enemies to this list somehow. Probably you already have a list or an array, wich behaves the same for this purpose.

foreach (Enemy E in MyEnemyList)
{
    E.enemyMoveSpeed += 1; //if you are incrementing the speed of everyone by 1.
    //or any other option you think is better
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to synchronize it with time. The update loop tries to run at 1/16 of a second.

Comment: Thank you for this code however I get a message saying that the property is inaccesible.

Comment: @user2459750 You need to make the property `public`. `public int enemyMoveSpeed { get; set; }`.

Comment: This will only affect current enemies, not new ones. OP seems to want to affect only new enemies.

Comment: It will affect all enemies in the list. Of course he will need to add new enemies to the "AllEnemies" list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static property for the new speed, and in your Enemy constructor you can set the instance property to match this.

Something like

```
class Enemy
{
    public static int NewEnemySpeed { get; set;}

    public int Speed {get; set;}

    public Enemy()
    {
        Speed = NewEnemySpeed;
    }

}
```

From your Game1.Update, you can do this

```
Enemy.NewEnemySpeed = ..//some new speed
```

Comment: This will only affect new instances. If you want this to apply to both current and new enemies, then combine this answer with Daniel's.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. This does not give me any errors but does not change the property. I know it is hard for you to judge the way I have written this, I was mainly following the XNA 2D game tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you.

```
public class Enemy
{
    public Enemy()
    {
        EnemyState = new EnemyState { IsDirty = true, Position = Vector2.Zero };
        Speed = 3.0f;
    }

    public EnemyState State { get; set }
    public float Speed { get; set; }
}

public class EnemyState
{
    public bool IsDirty { get; set }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    // If should spawn enemy
    // var enemy = new Enemy();
    // enemy.State.Position = // TODO insert starting position
    // enemies.Add(enemy);
    // Find all enemies that should be moved
    // Set IsDirty = true;

    // Move each enemy that IsDirty
    timer -= elapsed;
    if (timer < 0)
    {
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies.Where(e => e.State.IsDirty))
        {
            enemy.State.Position.X += enemy.Speed;
            enemy.State.IsDirty = false;
        }

        timer = TIMER; //Reset Timer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, whenever I start asking questions I come up with the answer myself.